# Xamarin Forms CarouselView does not show images

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, model

I have two Models and a ViewModels for articles and posts from DB . One of them like this :

```
public class ArticleData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundImage { get; set; }
    public string Quote { get; set; }
    public string QuoteAuthor { get; set; }
    public string When { get; set; }
    public string Followers { get; set; }
    public string Likes { get; set; }
}
```

and i use BackgroundImage in CarouselView like this :

```
<CarouselView
    HeightRequest="300"
    Margin="0"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    ItemsSource="{ Binding Images.Articles }">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                    Source="{ Binding BackgroundImage }"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill"
                    Aspect="AspectFill" />
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

And there is no problem with CarouselView and it shows images . But with another Model that likes this

```
public class FollowingsPostResponse
{
    public List<FPostModel> data { get; set; }
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class FPostModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<string> images { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string userProfileImage { get; set; }
    public string cityName { get; set; }
    public int likesCounts { get; set; }
    public string postCaption { get; set; }
}
```

and use like this

```
<CarouselView
                HeightRequest="300"
                Margin="0"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                ItemsSource="{ Binding Home.Post }">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                Source="{ Binding images }"
                                VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

CarouselView does not show anythings . What's the problem ?

Comment: `images` is a `List<string>` - `ffimageloading:CachedImage` expects a **single** image, not a `List`

Comment: @Jason Thank you . Witch control should I use ?

Comment: I don't know what it is you're trying to do.  If you want to show multiple images for each page of the carousel, then you should probably try CollectionView

Comment: @Jason I want to build something like instagram's post with multiple images

Comment: You could use  `CollectionView`  to binding `List<string> images`  in each CarouselView page.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thankx . Do you have any Tutorial link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jason and LeoZhu-MSFT

I solved my problem like this :

```
<CarouselView x:Name="MainCarouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding images}" Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="150">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding .}"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

ItemsSource="{Binding images}" because CarouselView is in CollectionView with ItemsSource="{Binding Home.Post}"